# Are introductory phrases such as 'In walked the girl...' and 'Down the hill they went...' correct?

Tags: style

I'm helping to proofread a friend's novel manuscript and I cannot find the answer to this on Google. To me, it reads oddly, but I would like to know if there are any established rules for this. Also, if these kinds of phrases are acceptable, is there a particular way to reference them? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your question does not appear to be about Academia as defined in the help center. See what's on topic at https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: And the "rules" might be a valid matter for academics to ponder. There is actually academics beyond science and math (I'm told).

Comment: I'd call them correct... but you probably might think they are awkward because I think they risk being cliché...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are acceptable in creative writing. They might be awkward in scientific writing, but for a novel, the phrasing of the author is to be honored unless it is confusing. But even ambiguous phrases might be well within the intent of the author.

You can ask the friend if you like, of course.

"The girl walked in..." is boring. "In walked the girl..." is more interesting. People don't want to read boring novels.

So, I guess the rule is "Don't be boring". But overdoing any creative trick can, itself, be boring.

Answer (score 3):

Such phrases are, in general, grammatical, and do appear in fiction written by authors generally considered good writers. There is no special or specific rule for such phrases. Whether such a phrase works well in a particular passage depends on the contest, and possibly the tone or effect the author is aiming at. Without context one cannot really say more.

As the answer by @Buffy says, any such compositional device can become boring if overused. But it can also become part of the style of the author.

This is more a matter of assessing the style and quality of the writing, than of proofreading for errors. It is the kind of thing that a "story doctor" or "test reader" might do. But in that case it must be assessed as part of the whole manuscript, to see how it aids or harms the effect of the work as a whole.

Comment: +1 Absolutely agree. Phrases like these can work beautifully or flop spectacularly depending on how you use them.  Used correctly, they can focus attention on a turning point, character or emotion and liven up the narrative. If the context is wrong, or it is overused, however, it can be jarring to the point of irritating the reader and making them abandon the strory.